# Django error relation "auth_user" does not exist using multiple database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-users, django-database

I'm working on Django 1.9 and python 3.3 project using multiple databases (different schema in a same postgresql database). When I try to migrate the project for the first time, I'm getting this error

```
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying MyApp.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  relation "auth_user" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 90, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

This error seems to appeard in other projects when the `auth_user` table isn't migrated. In my case beginning my migration with `manage.py migrate auth` before migrating the app who need it doesn't solve the problem.

I suspect that the problem come from the use of different database in Django. My `auth_user` table is stored in the **default database** and the content of the *models.py* is routed to an **other database**.

Is the migration process looking for the `auth_user` table in the same database than my app database? Is it something absolutely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer to the problem

It is in fact a cross database reference problem. Django can't create cross database foreign keys.

From the [Django 1.8 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations) (and there isn't any solution in the next versions (current version is 1.10)) :

> ## Cross-database relations
>
> Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or
>   many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases. If you have
>   used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign
>   key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be
>   internal to a single database.
>
> This is because of referential integrity. In order to maintain a
>   relationship between two objects, Django needs to know that the
>   primary key of the related object is valid. If the primary key is
>   stored on a separate database, it’s not possible to easily evaluate
>   the validity of a primary key.
>
> If you’re using Postgres, Oracle, or MySQL with InnoDB, this is
>   enforced at the database integrity level – database level key
>   constraints prevent the creation of relations that can’t be validated.
>
> However, if you’re using SQLite or MySQL with MyISAM tables, there is
>   no enforced referential integrity; as a result, you may be able to
>   ‘fake’ cross database foreign keys. However, this configuration is not
>   officially supported by Django

## How to workaround and keep separate databases

In my case, because router are working, there is a little hack to simplify the cross database objects.

```
class CrossDBUser(models.Model):
    user = models.IntegerField()

    def get_user(self):
        return User.objects.get(id=self.user)

    def set_user(self, user):
        self.user = user.id

class MyClassWithCrossDB(CrossDBUser):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    field2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

With this I can use the method `set_user` and `get_user` to work with the user stored in my object `MyClassWithCrossDB`.

Of course it's not perfect because it doesn't allow automated actions like `on_delete=models.CASCADE` and I'm obliged to work with methods instead of the instance variable. But it is a solution to workaround.

Comment: In 2022, Django 4.0, is there a better way to do this?